# How to make a large codebase easier to understand

Tags: documentation, large-scale-project

Suppose that I am developing a relatively large project. I have already documented all my classes and functions with Doxygen, however, I had an idea to put a "programmer's notes" on each source code file.

The idea behind this is to explain in layman's terms **how** a specific class works (and not only **why** as most comments do). In other words, to give fellow programmers an other-view of how a class works.

For example:

```
/*
 * PROGRAMMER'S NOTES:
 *
 * As stated in the documentation, the GamepadManager class 
 * reads joystick joystick input using SDL and 'parses' SDL events to
 * Qt signals.
 *
 * Most of the code here is about goofing around the joystick mappings.
 * We want to avoid having different joystick behaviours between
 * operating systems to have a more integrated user experience, since
 * we don't want team members to have a bad surprise while
 * driving their robots with different laptops.
 *
 * Unfortunately, we cannot use SDL's GamepadAPI because the robots
 * are interested in getting the button/axes numbers, not the "A" or
 * "X" button.
 *
 * To get around this issue, we created a INI file for the most common 
 * controllers that maps each joystick button/axis to the "standard" 
 * buttons and axes used by most teams. 
 *
 * We choose to use INI files because we can safely use QSettings
 * to read its values and we don't have to worry about having to use
 * third-party tools to read other formats.
 */
```

Would this be a good way to make a large project easier for new programmers/contributors to understand how it works? Aside from maintaining a consistent coding style and 'standard' directory organization, are there any 'standards' or recommendations for these cases?

Comment: Hell no. If your code is unreadable, documentation won't help.

Comment: @Telastyn - How many projects are willing to take the time to do this, but still write unreadable code? May not be causation, but I'll bet there is a good correlation.

Comment: @jeffo - the problem is that taking the time to do this can happen once. The time to keep code readable happens over time. I've been at places with this sort of documentation, done when the project was young, or when Joe the Perfectionist was still on the team. It then got abandoned and the comments lingered on, no longer accurate.

Comment: This is not to say the idea is not useful; it is that in real life good ideas that do not result in immediate benefits for its laborers tend to be neglected, and the out-of-date information might become unreliable over time, such that the readers of such notes need to treat it with some suspicion.

Comment: At a higher level at least, an out-of-code prose description of what a project does, how it works, and what tradeoffs have been made in the architecture is invaluable. This sort of a document is a must-read for a newcomer *before* they take a code tour. There is a lot of my-methodology-is-too-radical-for-docs-dude bullshit around the net, and while it *is* true that an initial arch doc and an evolving arch doc won't align, a prose description is necessary for anyone to quickly grasp a large, non-trivial codebase. Here is a (poor) example: http://zxq9.com/erlmud/html/001-002_architecture.html

Comment: @zxq9: Architecture/high-level docs have thankfully become a standard culture of github. So much so that I won't use a library with an incomplete README.md file. The github solution to rotting documentation is that inaccurate documentation generate a bug report

Comment: @Telastyn: This has nothing to do with whether the code is readable or not (and I hope it is). Documenting design rationale is absolutely important.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - but not _in code_. There are better tools for doing that.

Comment: @Telastyn: Yeah, maybe. Personally I'd write it in a standalone doc. But comment blocks at the top of source files isn't so bad.

Comment: One thing to note: This has certainly many upsides, but once your design changes, you have to make sure to update this documentation too. I am not aware of any tool-support for changing documentation (unlike for code refactoring).

Comment: There's documentation for _users_ of your class, and then there's documentation for _maintainers_ of your class. As a user of the class, I don't really care about the workarounds you had to implement to make X talk to Y. But if I have to maintain your code, or even if I have to _read_ it for some reason, (which almost amounts to the same thing) then I care a lot.

Comment: In Java you document for users of the code in the java doc. You document for the maintanence programmer inside the class / method.

Comment: that's nice to understand what a specific source file does, but it doesn't tell you anything about how all the different source files fit and work together. It's also imperative that it gets properly maintained, changed with the source file. And in my experience THAT is where such comments fall, they tend to not be properly maintained because there's "no time for it", things get changed rapidly to meet changing requirements or bugfixes that need to go out NOW and all that happens is a note somewhere "TODO update documentation" which then never gets done.

Comment: @Telastyn On mondays I am Joe the Perfectionist. Fridays make me Disaster Bob

Comment: I love this. It includes a lot of the implicit understanding you have of the codebase, that's not written anywhere, and by writing it, you've done a huge favor for the next guy.

Comment: I just took over an Android app 4+ years in development that has basically no documentation. You know what would be nice right now? Documentation like yours.

Comment: Are you documenting your requirements in SRS format or P-Spec format? That would be helpful too.

Answer (score 142):

This is awesome.  I wish more software developers took the time and effort to do this.  It:

- States in plain English what the class does (i.e. it's responsibility),
- Provides useful supplementary information about the code without repeating verbatim what the code already says,
- Outlines some of the design decisions and why they were made, and
- Highlights some of the gotchas that might befall the next person reading your code.

Alas, many programmers fall into the camp of "if code is written properly, it shouldn't have to be documented."  Not true.  There are many implied relationships between code classes, methods, modules and other artifacts that are not obvious from just reading the code itself.

An experienced coder can carefully craft a design having clear, easily-understandable architecture that is obvious without documentation.  But how many programs like that have you actually seen?

Comment: And why the "Mythical Man Month" becomes a self-fulfilling prophecy, no one took the time to write all this out for the new dev when it was fresh on their mind and the project didn't fall behind.

Comment: I agree with every point you make here. I don't like the term the OP used in his post `how a class works`. This changes with time and maintenance. Though my team does not put the above in the source. We maintain a wiki with decisions and copy the slack channel discussion about design decisions raw into a document (We provide a link from the decision summary and conclusion to the raw notes so we don't have to re-hash old decisions). All done neatly in github (so it is all in one place).

Comment: My only issue is applying this globally. This class is complex enough, with certain gotchas available, clearly it's really useful (although you still end up dealing with Comment Rot). When a class is more obvious, the comment can be a bit superfluous.

Comment: "An experienced coder can carefully craft a design having clear, easily-understandable architecture that is obvious without documentation. But how many programs like that have you actually seen"

While this is true, the quality of the documentation is never better than the quality of the code. Well architected code tends to have good, if pointless, documentation. Poorly architected code has comments like "increment x by 1"

Comment: I absolutely agree with this answer, and if I found something like the OP's example in code I would just be so happy. Just a single addition: consider adding a *date* to your comment, just to give an hint to eventual readers as to the freshness of the description, and update it every time you update the text.

Comment: Having just taken over an Android app 4+ years in development with a lot of out-of-date dependencies, having basically zero documentation is making my job as a maintainer very difficult.  ***I would love to have documentation like OP presented***. It would make my life a lot easier, and save me 5 hours each week trying to figure out what the hell a class is doing.

Answer (score 37):

The key to working with a large codebase is not having to read the entire codebase to make a change. To enable a programmer to quickly find the code he is looking for, code should be organized, and the organization apparent. That is, each logical unit in the code, from the executable, the library, the namespace, down to the individual class should have a clearly apparent responsibility. I would therefore not just document source files, but also the directories they reside in.

Your programmer's notes also give background on design decisions. While this can be valuable information, I would separate it from the statement of responsibility (to enable the reader to choose whether he wants to read about the responsibility of the class or its design rationale), and move it as close to the source it describes as possible, to maximize the chance the documentation is updated when the code is (documentation is only useful if we can trust in its accuracy - outdated documentation can be worse than none!).

That said, documentation should remain DRY, i.e. not repeat information that could have been expressed in code or was already described elsewhere (phrases like "as the documentation states" are a warning sign). In particular, future maintainers will be just a proficient in the project's programming language as they are in English; paraphrasing the implementation in comments (which I see altogether too often when people are proud of their documentation) has no benefit, and is likely to diverge from the implementation, in particular if the documentation is not near the code it describes.

Finally, the structure of documentation should be standardized across the project so everyone can find it (it's a royal mess of Peter documents in the bug tracker, Sue in the wiki, Alan in the readme, and John in the source code ...).

Comment: Your first sentence is exactly how I view this. Large codebases should be composed as a number of smaller components where a new programmer can reliably change one without endangering any of the others.

Comment: **move it as close to the source it describes as possible, to maximize the chance the documentation is updated when the code is**. This is valuable experience.

Comment: DRY as a guideline for the documentation is a very good point! That automatically sets the focus right and forbids the famously obnoxious "// increment x by 1" comments.

Answer (score 13):

I would not agree this is a very good approach, mainly due to

1. When you refactor your project, move methods around, the documentation breaks.
2. If documentation is not properly updated, it will result in more confusion than help understanding the code.

If you have unit tests for each method/ integration tests for each module, it would be a self documentation more maintainable and easier to understand compared to code comments.

Yes, having a proper directory structure definitely going to help.

Comment: +1 for Tests being the best way to understand a code base. Unit tests, integration tests, acceptance tests all tell the story about how the application is supposed to work, and how it's supposed to be used.

Answer (score 8):

I'm personally a fan of a high-level design document - preferably written BEFORE any code - that gives an overview of the design and a list of classes and resources.  A top-down design greatly simplifies things - yours might be "game engine -> hardware -> controllers -> joystick"; thus, a new programmer told "fix the 'a' button on the 'xyz controller" would at least know where to start looking.

Too many modern languages tend to break code into hundreds of tiny files, so just finding the correct file can be a challenge on even a moderate project.

Comment: 20 years ago all my code was in one huge file.  Now it is in thousands of small files and test files.  There's a good reason for this and it reflects 20 years of software development (the general ecosystem, not my knowledge).  Waaay too long for a comment though.

Comment: ah, the old waterfall method of writing a single, all encompassing, immutable, Truth before coding even starts and make it impossible to deviate in the implementation from said Truth.

Comment: @jwenting: You don't have to take it that far.  But it's still good to have *some* idea what you are building.

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course, you should have the initial business requirements laid out and a rough architecture. But the way DW describes it it reads like he wants an old fashioned architecture document laying out everything down to method and variable names.

Comment: Certainly without the caveat of how to properly break this down and where to break the rules, you're going to very quickly have a document that's either out of date or a millstone. "I need to add a new class; to Documanto, the Behemoth that eats time!"

Comment: @deworde: I read that as "too lazy to maintain documentation."

Comment: @RobertHarvey "Lazy" is too often a term used to justify pointless work. Having updated a "design document" of UML that was more complex than the code it described, and was only ever read by the project architect, and failed to reveal several key concepts, including anywhere a bug might actually exist. I've lost faith in the inherent power of documentation to solve problems.

Good documentation serves a purpose and is thus maintained, if only by the readers. Bad documentation is dictated by rules and quickly trends towards valueless verbiage.

Comment: @deworde: All true.  Bad documentation is created by those who don't understand the purpose good documentation serves.

Answer (score 6):

If the code base is large - I try to provide a design **document that maps out the key elements of its design and the implementation**. The intention here is not to detail any of the classes used, but provide a key to code and the thought that went into the design. It gives a overarching context to the system, its components and the application thereof.

Things to include in the design document are;

- Application architecture
- Logical code structure
- Data flows
- Key patterns used and the motivation behind their use
- Code source structure
- How to build it (this offers insight into implicit dependencies and physical code source structure)

Following on from this, **documentation for the classes, and functions/methods should be completed as appropriate**. In particular the public API; it should be clear what the following all are in each case;

- Preconditions
- Effects
- Invariants
- Exception conditions (throws)

Comment: +1 Better than describing each class, as that will get out of date way faster than an overall design.

Answer (score 4):

The most important rule I have found for making it easier for new developers to understand a codebase is **perfect agreement is expensive.**

If new developers must perfectly understand the system they are working on, it prevents all opportunities for on the job learning.  I think the programmer's notes are an excellent start, but I would go further.  Try to write code that, if approached anew, would allow a developer to figure out what they are doing on the fly, rather than requiring them to learn before they do.  Little things like asserts for cases you know can never occur, along with comments explaining why the assert is valid, go a long way.  So does writing code which fails gracefully rather than segfaulting if you do anything wrong.

Comment: My rule is that comments should be about **WHY**, not **HOW**. The code describes HOW.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen large classes with documentation, and after reading the documentation I haven't got a clue what this class is supposed to be good for and why anyone would use it! And at the same time, I had a need for some functionality and I was absolutely sure there must be a class to handle it, and couldn't find it anywhere - because there was no documentation that led me from what I needed to the class doing it.

So the first thing that I would want in the documentation is just a few sentences what a class does, and why I would want to use it. The comments in the original question are doing quite well in that respect. After reading these comments, if I had a joystick that doesn't work well because I can't interpret the values it delivers, I would know what code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what @meriton said, break the code down into separate components. Even better, break down the codebase into separate *packages* (JARs, gems, eggs, whatever) to make it even more clear how the components are separated. If there is a bug, a developer only needs to find the *package* where the bug is, and (hopefully) only fix it there. Not to mention, it's easier to do unit testing, and you get to take advantage of dependency management.

Another solution: make the codebase smaller. The less code there is, the easier it is to understand. Refactor out unused or duplicated code. Use [declarative programming techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784664/what-is-the-difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-programming). This takes effort, of course, and often isn't possible or practical. But it's a worthy goal. As Jeff Atwood has written: [The Best Code Is No Code At All](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-best-code-is-no-code-at-all/)

Answer (score -1):

For complex systems it may be worth it to not just document each file, but their interactions and hierarchy, and how the program structures and why.

For example a game engine is usually quite complex and its hard to decide what calls what after hundred layers of abstraction. It may be worth creating a file like "Architecture.txt" to explain how and why is the code structured like this, and why there is that pointless looking abstraction layer there.

Answer (score -7):

This can be partly because it is hard for a single programmer to write it, as each individual understands only their part of project.

Sometimes you can get this info from the notes of the project manager , but that is all you will get, as they will rarely rewrite their notes in this format.

Comment: If you look at github you'll find a lot of projects that have this kind of note in a README.md file. It's become so much a part of the culture of git in general and javascript projects in particular to most people won't use a library that does not have this sort of high level documentation. So it's untrue that "no programmer would write it" since you only need to look at something like jQuery or socket.io and find programmers who write such things. It has also become a culture that README files that are not accurate generate bug reports.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, which was looking for reasons why the documentation style proposed would or wouldn't work, and also for documentation standards.

Comment: If you have a team of programmers working on a product, and each programmer only understands the specific code that they worked on, then not only is your team incredibly dysfunctional with an absurd bus factor, but one questions the quality of the code. How does one integrate code into a product without understanding the rest of the code in the same system??!?